# how to implement datepicker in asp.net using jquery?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, datepicker

```
    <script src="<%=("../Scripts/jquery-1.6.1.min.js") %>" type="text/javascript" />
   <script src="<%=("../Scripts/jquery-datePicker.js") %>" type="text/javascript" />

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {

     $("#txtDate").datepicker();       

    });   

   </script>
```

I have used this code but it doesnot show me the popup calender on click on textbox.
what can be the problem.
it doesnot give any error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not set path directly? and close script tag with this `</script>`

```
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.6.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-datePicker.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
```

Use ClientID for server control

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {

     $("#<%= txtDate.ClientID %>").datepicker();       

    });   

   </script>
```

you can also use ready function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#<%= txtDate.ClientID %>").datepicker();       
});
</script>
```

if ID selector doesn't work then use class selector it is good for ASP.NET server control

```
<asp:TextBox ruat="server" ID="txtDate" CssClass="DateField"></asp:TextBox>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
     $(".DateField").datepicker();       
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should use the document.ready function

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#txtDate").datepicker();       
});
```

Answer (score 0):

ID of ASP.NET server control is different than that of the normal HTML ID. So if you are using a Server control, then run your code, open the page source, get the ID that is displayed in the page source and use this ID instead of txtDate.

Also use

```
$(document).ready(function() { $("#<id>").datepicker(); });
```

Comment: It couldnot be run.it just shows error of object expected.I m afraid if i have attached enough src or not